# Debugging ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED on Windows API (CreateProcessAsUser)

Tags: java, c++, windows, winapi, jna

I'm using the JNA to call [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) from the Windows API. I'm passing a simple command to [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw):

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\SysWOW64\whoami.exe > whoami.txt
```

Basically, it should print the current user (obtained through `whoami.exe`) to a file called `whoami.txt`.
**It succeeds in this.** After executing my Java program, I see a new file `whoami.txt` containing my username.

However, I print the return value of [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) and see that the error code goes from `0` to `5` immediately after calling [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw). The [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) says that `5` is the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` error.

I ran the Java process from the Command Prompt running as Administrator. It's worth noting that I'm not switching users when calling [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw).

My hunch is that one of the many arguments to this function is causing a superficial permission error that gets handled gracefully. However, it could also be that I'm missing some user right.

I'm new to Windows and unfamiliar with better ways to debug such an error. What tools would you all recommend for getting more information about the access denied error? On Linux, `journalctl` would be of great help here.

Here is my code:

```java
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow
final STARTUPINFOW.ByReference startupInfoW =
    new STARTUPINFOW.ByReference();
startupInfoW.cb = startupInfoW.size();
startupInfoW.lpReserved = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.lpDesktop = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.lpTitle = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.dwFlags
    = startupInfoW.dwX = startupInfoW.dwY
    = startupInfoW.dwXSize = startupInfoW.dwYSize
    = startupInfoW.dwXCountChars = startupInfoW.dwYCountChars
    = startupInfoW.dwFillAttribute
    = startupInfoW.wShowWindow
    = 0;
startupInfoW.cbReserved2  = 0;
startupInfoW.lpReserved2 = Pointer.NULL;
startupInfoW.hStdInput = startupInfoW.hStdOutput
    = startupInfoW.hStdError
    = Pointer.NULL;
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information
final PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference processInformation =
    new PROCESS_INFORMATION.ByReference();
processInformation.hProcess = processInformation.hThread
    = Pointer.NULL;
processInformation.dwProcessId = processInformation.dwThreadId
    = 0;
// Converts string to char array with 0 as last element.
final char[] whoamiCmd = toCString(
    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\whoami.exe > whoami.txt"
);
System.out.printf(
    "last err code = %d\n",
    ErrHandlingApi.INSTANCE.GetLastError()
);
final boolean createProcessOk = MyProcessThreadsApi.INSTANCE
    .CreateProcessAsUserW(
        userPrimaryToken.getValue(),
        Pointer.NULL,
        whoamiCmd,
        Pointer.NULL,
        Pointer.NULL,
        false,
        WinBase.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        new PointerByReference(),
        Pointer.NULL,
        startupInfoW,
        processInformation
    );
System.out.printf(
    "last err code = %d\n",
    ErrHandlingApi.INSTANCE.GetLastError()
);
System.out.printf("ok = %b\n", createProcessOk);
System.out.printf(
    "dwProcessId = %d\n", processInformation.dwProcessId
);
```

```java
public static char[] toCString(final String str) {
    final char[] cString = new char[str.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        cString[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    // c-strings end in 0 for lack of bounds checking
    cString[cString.length-1] = 0;
    return cString;
}
```

```
C:\Users\zjoseal\Desktop>whoami
ant\zjoseal

C:\Users\zjoseal\Desktop>java -cp windows-credentials-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main
...
last err code = 0
last err code = 5
ok = true
dwProcessId = 6628

C:\Users\zjoseal\Desktop>type whoami.txt
ant\zjoseal
```

### Edits to Code 1

Some of you asked whether the toCString method could be responsible for the error code changing. It just copies the contents of a string to a `char[]` with and appended a `0` to make it a null-terminated c-string. I moved it before the first print statement to guarantee that it's not  responsible for the error code.

Someone also pointed out that the print statement could mess up the error code, so I made sure that the GetLastError call happens immediately after the CreateProcessAsUserW call.

Comment: The third parameter to `CreateProcessAsUserW` (the command-line argument) requires a modifiable buffer of characters.  Does the Java code you have now provide this?  [Read the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw).  Note, there is a huge difference between a `LPCWSTR` and a `LPWSTR` -- the former can be a string-literal, the latter must be a modifiable array of characters.

Comment: Also, you're supposed to call `GetLastError` **immediately** after calling the API function.  Issuing `System.out` calls before getting the last error renders the error reporting useless and misleading.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wouldn't think a Java-side method call would have any impact here?  It seems that only if there's another WinAPI call on the same thread would the last error be overwritten?

Comment: @DanielWiddis The Java code may call an underlying OS function, which may reset the last error flag.  I learned this fact from writing C++ code that "delayed" the querying of the last error, and called a couple of seemingly non-related, non Windows API functions.  I was wrong in assuming that the Windows last error flag can be reset.

Comment: Should say: "I was wrong in assuming that the Windows last error flag **can't** be reset."

Comment: exec *cmd.exe* is wrong and senseless. you need exec *whoami.exe* direct (of course *whoami.exe* not need exec too - all info easy get direct without this process). `userPrimaryToken.getValue()` no sense - simply pass 0 here with same effect or call `CreateProcessW`. and `GetLastError` have sense only if api (not any) fail

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I made a few edits.

1. I indeed pass a modifiable buffer of characters.
2. I moved the GetLastError call to be immediately after the CreateProcessAsUserW call.

However, that didn't change the output. I still get an error code.

Comment: @RbMm I'm doing a proof of concept to using the JNA to create processes as other users. Eventually, I want to switch up the user, so I want to pass it a real user token.

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre you need have *SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege* in general case. exec *cmd.exe* is error in any case. and call `GetLastError` no sense if `CreateProcess` returned true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output you've indicated the variable `createProcessOk`, which is the return value of `CreateProcessAsUserW()`, is `true` (nonzero).  The [WinAPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) for that function states:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Since the function succeeded, that's all you need to know.  You should not be checking `GetLastError` unless the function fails.

`GetLastError` works on a per-thread basis.  The result [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror):

> Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed. **If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set**; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.

Since the function succeeded, it is "not documented to set the last-error code."  The "5" result you are seeing is "simply the most recent last-error code to have been set."  As you've indicated in your question, there was likely some internal WinAPI call as part of the internal implementation that resulted in the error, but had a graceful fallback.

As [@PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) has indicated in the comments, the API requires a modifiable Unicode (wide) string (`LPWSTR`) as the third argument. Your code has a mysterious `toCString()` call there which you haven't posted the source code for.  If that method does not produce a modifiable UTF-16 character array, it's probably the source of the error, and Windows is helpfully processing the result anyway.

Comment: I made edits to clarify the c-string issue. `toCString` returns a 0-terminated `char[]` which meets the null-terminated 16-bit modifiable array of characters requirement. Ok, I agree with your analysis. However, let's say that I needed to dig into the cause of that error (imagine the function was returning false). What could I do to investigate the cause? Is there something on Windows that could trace what's going on?

Comment: @JoséAlvaradoTorre As a normal user, you can't.  I took a peek at the Windows source code, where the public API calls an internal process creation function (`CreateProcessInternalW`) which does a whole bunch of other API calls. Scanning through, not all those failures result in the create process failure (e.g., calls to `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` involving breakaway flags).   In addition, you're calling the `CMD.EXE` app and all its internal API calls, plus `WHOAMI.EXE` and all its internal API calls.  Any of those could have an expected WinAPI failure handled gracefully.

Comment: If the function returned false with that error, you'd be pretty sure you didn't have access to one of the executable paths involved, as it returns immediately with that error in that case.

Comment: Ok, that's fair. I won't worry about the error unless the function returns false.